# top alignment of table in table

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment, collcell

I have a small :) problem with latex.
I wanted to put an enumeration into a tabular, but this didn't work. Than I worked on a workaround ending up with the following code.

My Problem: The cells are not aligned at the top. I read something about adding `\vfill` or `\vspace{0pt}`. But that didn't work.

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half, fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{p{.27\textwidth}|p{.27\textwidth}|p{.27\textwidth}}
        OEM     & MNO       & 3PL\\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}{@{\tabitem}p{.22\textwidth}}
            Manufacturing at low cost\\
            Direct connections to suppliers and local distributors\\
        \end{tabular}
        %\vspace{15em}
    %
        &\begin{tabular}{@{\tabitem}p{.22\textwidth}}
            Customer relations\\
            Distribution network (stores, website, etc.)\\
            Brand management and marketing\\
            network technology
        \end{tabular} %\vspace{0pt}
    %
        &\begin{tabular}{@{\tabitem}p{.22\textwidth}}
            Logistics services and solutions \\
            Value added IT\\
            After sales services\\

    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Well of course it doesn't has to look like this as long as the aim is achieved :P
I hope you have an idea. Thanks a lot for your ideas

Best

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Enumerations need a parbox `p` column within tables. By the way, there is `stray` code at the end of your example or accidentally copied in between

Comment: Where does `\tabitem` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists like `enumerate` or `itemize` cannot occur directly in as content of a tabular cell -- they must be enclosed in a `\parbox` or, even better, using `p{somewidth}` - column specifier.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half, fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}%
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{p{.27\textwidth}|p{.27\textwidth}|p{.27\textwidth}}
    OEM     & MNO       & 3PL\tabularnewline \hline
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Manufacturing at low cost
      \item Direct connections to suppliers and local distributors
         \end{enumerate}
      &
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Customer relations
      \item Distribution network (stores, website, etc.)
      \item Brand management and marketing
      \item network technology
      \end{enumerate} 
      &
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Logistics services and solutions 
      \item Value added IT
      \item After sales services
      \end{enumerate}\tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{P{.27\textwidth}|P{.27\textwidth}|P{.27\textwidth}}
    OEM     & MNO       & 3PL\tabularnewline \hline
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Manufacturing at low cost
      \item Direct connections to suppliers and local distributors
         \end{enumerate}
      &
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Customer relations
      \item Distribution network (stores, website, etc.)
      \item Brand management and marketing
      \item network technology
      \end{enumerate} 
      &
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Logistics services and solutions 
      \item Value added IT
      \item After sales services
      \end{enumerate}\tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the columns are fairly narrow, using full justification (the default method of the `p` column type) tends to generate huge interword gaps. You may want to load the `array` and `ragged2e` packages and provide the instruction `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`.  That way, the three columns can use the new `P` column type, which typesets its material in raggedright mode while still allowing hyphenation. (If `\raggedright` were used instead of `\RaggedRight`, no hyphenation would be allowed, resulting in extremely ragged-looking paragraphs...)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, I know of this possibility, but I addressed the basic problem as first order problem... I will improve it, promised!

Comment: @Mico: Changed to your propositions!

Comment: This may be not very nice, but I included an `@{}` in the tabular definition because I thougth that the distance betweent the column separator and the list/enumeration symbol is to big.`\begin{tabular}{@{}P{.27\textwidth}|@{}P{.30\textwidth}|@{}P{.27\textwidth}}`

Comment: @benni: That's your decision -- I just used somehow the original code... go ahead

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christian!!!
That's the answer. For all others, here is the working code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half, fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{p{.27\textwidth}|p{.27\textwidth}|p{.27\textwidth}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OEM}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MNO}      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3PL}\\ \hline
    \begin{itemize}
        \item   Manufacturing at low cost
        \item Direct connections to suppliers and local distributors
    \end{itemize}
%
    &\begin{itemize}
    \item   Customer relations
    \item   Distribution network (stores, website, etc.)
    \item   Brand management and marketing
    \item   network technology
    \end{itemize}
%
    &\begin{itemize}
    \item   Logistics services and solutions
    \item   Value added IT
    \item   After sales services
    \item   Inventory management\,/\,warehousing
    \end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You may want to mention explicitly the differences between Christian's answer and your own. E.g., use of `itemize` instead of `enumerate`, and centering the respective column headers. Incidentally, if you write `\slash` instead of `/`, LaTeX will know automatically that a line break may follow the slash symbol.

Comment: thank you mico, I didn't know that about `\slash` definitely a value information